# Visual Studio Backups folder is empty

Tags: visual-studio

I am running visual studio 2012.

I have turned on the AutoRecover feature to backup files every 2 minutes, and keep them for 30 days.

Unfortunately , when I navigate to...

Documents\Visual Studio \Backup Files\

All of the folders contained in there are empty...

Is the another location where they could be saved to?